# How can I write a function in real mode (assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, att, bare-metal, real-mode

I have been learning how to write bootable programs in assembly x86 in real mode for a couple weeks, but I wasn't able to make any big progress, sice I could't find on my own any free good course in bare metal programming for x86 cpu-s in assembly.
Therefore I am attempting to learn through trial and error, but the more I try the more I go wrong. Today I was trying to understand how to handle stack and how to build a function in real mode using AT&T assemby, and I wrote this code, thinking it made sense:

```
        .code16
        .global init

# PRINT SI
print:
        push    %bp
        mov     %sp, %bp
        sub     $16, %sp
        pusha
        mov     $0xe, %ah
print_char:
        lodsb
        cmp     $0, %al
        je      print_end
        int     $0x10
        jmp     print_char
print_end:
        popa
        mov     %bp, %sp
        pop     %bp
        ret

init:
        mov     $msg, %si
        call    print
        hlt

msg:    .asciz "Test number one..."


        .fill 510-(.-print), 1, 0
        .word 0xaa55
```

It should print "Test number one..." on the screen, but using qemu it prints just "S" on the screen, like this:

[image]

Can someone figure out where did I go wrong and why?

Comment: The BIOS jumps to the beginning of your boot sector. It does not know that you want to start at `init`. So add a `jmp init` at the beginning or move the `init` block up to the start.

Comment: I forgot to specify that I assembled the code in this way:

$ as boot.s -o boot.o
$ ld boot.o -o boot.bin --oformat binary -Ttext 0x7c00 -e init

This means that I told to the linker how to find the entry point (-e init). Shouldn't it work?

Comment: That is irrelevant since plain binary format has no header where the entry point could be specified. Really, the linker should warn you about that. The BIOS always jumps to physical address 0x7c00.

Comment: Thanks, it did work ideed! I aswered before trying.

Comment: @NoBorders: Note that `lodsb` uses `ds:si` and the "direction" flag, and both of these could be left set to anything by the BIOS (so you should set `ds` correctly and do a `cld` to clear the direction flag before the `lodsb`), and `hlt` just tells the CPU to wait until the next IRQ occurs before continuing and won't stop the CPU for long (and should be inside an endless loop if you want the CPU to stop forever).